# Random selection of rows but with a constraint

Tags: r, data-analysis

[image: data snapshot]

I want a 3-4 different sets of 5 rows (each row should be from different cluster(2nd column)). How can we do this in R??

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "cluster(2nd column)" AND do provide some reproduicble data!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a good first post but next time please don't share data as images but use functions such as `dput()` to paste code that reproduces the example data directly into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr`solution:

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = 101:120,
  col2 = sample(1:5, 20, replace = T),
  col3 = sample(140:170, 20, replace = T))
```

Solution:

Here we sample exactly one row per level in `col2`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(col2) %>% sample_n(1) 
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   col2 [5]
   col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int>
1   106     1   161
2   117     2   163
3   109     3   148
4   102     4   161
5   104     5   170
```

You can store these samples in different dataframes and grab them in a list:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(col2) %>% sample_n(1)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(col2) %>% sample_n(1)
df3 <- df %>% group_by(col2) %>% sample_n(1)

df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
df_list
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   col2 [5]
   col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int>
1   118     1   146
2   117     2   163
3   112     3   167
4   102     4   161
5   108     5   158

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   col2 [5]
   col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int>
1   106     1   161
2   117     2   163
3   110     3   144
4   102     4   161
5   104     5   170

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   col2 [5]
   col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int>
1   106     1   161
2   119     2   149
3   109     3   148
4   113     4   161
5   104     5   170
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you try the code below

```
res <- split(df,with(df,ave(grp,grp,FUN = function(x) sample(seq_along(x)))))
```

which gives

```
> res
$`1`
    id grp
3  103   1
5  105   2
6  106   4
7  107   5
12 112   3

$`2`
    id grp
2  102   1
4  104   5
9  109   2
10 110   4
11 111   3

$`3`
   id grp
1 101   1
8 108   3
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 
109, 110, 111, 112), grp = c(1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 
3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

> df
    id grp
1  101   1
2  102   1
3  103   1
4  104   5
5  105   2
6  106   4
7  107   5
8  108   3
9  109   2
10 110   4
11 111   3
12 112   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expand.grid` to get all possible combinations of each group like:

```
expand.grid(split(seq_len(nrow(x)), x$cl))[1:4,]
#  1 2 3 4 5
#1 1 5 8 6 4
#2 2 5 8 6 4
#3 3 5 8 6 4
#4 1 9 8 6 4
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(cl = c(1,1,1,5,2,4,5,3,2,4,3,3))
```